# Evaluation context of @everywhere

Tags: module, parallel-processing, namespaces, julia

Consider the following code:

```
module Mod

    function f()
        @everywhere store(v) = println(12+v)
        g(3,Main.store)
    end

    function g(n,p)
        for i in 1:n
            p(8)
        end
    end

end

Mod.f()
```

The line of interest is `g(3,Main.store)`. Without specifying the module, execution of this snippet at the REPL (w.r.t `Main`) results in an `UnDefVarErrror: store`.

Is it per design that the line is not evaluated in the current `Module`? Why? The serial counterpart (without `@everywhere` runs fine without specifying `Main`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If my understanding is correct, the `@everywhere` macro essentially tells julia to execute the instruction `store(v) = println(12+v)` on *all* the processes (including the main process, i.e. the one running the REPL). In other words, this happens at *global* scope *per process*. Therefore it makes sense that after this step, you can access the `store` function via `Main.store`, i.e. at the outermost scope for the process, since it does not exist in the current scope (i.e. inside your module / `f` function).

I'm assuming by "serial counterpart" you mean directly typing in the REPL:

```
function f()
    store(v) = println(12+v)
    g(3, store)
end

function g(n,p)
    for i in 1:n
    p(8)
end

f()
```

in which case, yes this is a completely different scenario. The `store` function is now local to f(), and that's where you use it, so it wouldn't make sense to try and use a namespace qualifier to access it from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

This recently posted [issue](https://github.com/JuliaLang/julia/issues/18886) resolved all my issues. As it turns out I do not need to define the closure `store` `@everywhere`. It can simply be passed as data in `remotecall_wait`.

In other words the code posted by Tasos will simply work when additional processes are added before `using` the containing module.

Comment: Glad you found a solution to your problem, but in the interest of clarity I don't think the two are related. The problem with your code above wasn't one of passing a closure or not (you weren't). It was one of wrong scope. Having said that, it seems that closures are indeed a valid way of evaluating something easily on a worker; in fact, according to the documentation, turns out this is exactly what `@spawn` does. I agree with the author of that issue, it would have been good if this was made explicit in the documentation as it is very useful to know.

Comment: You are right, of course, about the nature of the issue. What I meant is that the referred GitHub issue removes the need to build code like the one in my original post. In addition without studying the expanded code, it is not trivial @everywhere should evaluate its argument expression in global module scope. Many thanks for your helpful input.